# using ObjectInputStream. when i use readObject() method the it give me and exception called EOFException

Tags: java, serialization, objectinputstream

This is the program I try to print a serialize object using ObjectInputStream's readObject() but end of the file the program is showing error like

```
java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
        at ReadStudent.main(ReadStudent.java:12)
```

How to solve it?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

class ReadStudent {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        try{
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("students.txt");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
            Student s;
            while((s = (Student) ois.readObject()) != null){
                System.out.println(s.getRoll() + "     " + s.getName());
            }
            ois.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the code serialize the object ? You have provided about deserializing the object.

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/serialization-in-java

Comment: That’s what it’s supposed to do. Your code is wrong in expecting a null. `readObject()` doesn’t return null at EOS. It throws this exception. Catch it.

Answer (score -1):

A Java comment on the `peekByte` method reads

> Peeks at (but does not consume) and returns the next byte value in
>    the stream, or throws EOFException if end of stream/block data has
>   been reached.

I would suggest to add an additional check in the `while` condition to verify if there are bytes available to read :

```
while(ois.available() > 0 && (s = (Student) ois.readObject()) != null)
```

Comment: `available()` is not a valid test for end of stream. See the Javadoc.

Answer (score -1):

Probable Solution would be like below code

```
import java.io.*;





public class SafeObjectInputStream extends ObjectInputStream {

    private static final int MAX_DEPTH = 100; // Maximum object graph depth

    public SafeObjectInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    protected void readStreamHeader() throws IOException {
        // Validate the stream header to ensure it's not tampered with
        // Optional: Implement your own header validation logic here
        super.readStreamHeader();
    }

    @Override
    protected ObjectStreamClass readClassDescriptor() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        // Limit the depth of object graph to prevent stack overflow attacks
        if (depth() > MAX_DEPTH) {
            throw new SecurityException("Object graph depth limit exceeded");
        }
        return super.readClassDescriptor();
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> resolveClass(ObjectStreamClass desc) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        // Implement your own class whitelist logic here
        String className = desc.getName();
        if (!isAllowedClass(className)) {
            throw new SecurityException("Class not allowed: " + className);
        }
        return super.resolveClass(desc);
    }

    private boolean isAllowedClass(String className) {
        // Implement your class whitelist logic here
        // For example, you could maintain a list of allowed classes
        // and check if the given class is in that list
        // In this example, we are allowing only classes in java.lang package
        return className.startsWith("java.lang");
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn’t solve any problem in the OP’s code. In any case mere code is not an answer. You have to explain.